# Wrap (overflowing) TextView between other Views

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

This is best explained with a picture:

[image]

(Presume picture is bounds of the parent)

As you can see, the text inside the TextView was too big to fit **beside** the first pill/chip View so it was bumped down to next row.. :(

(I am currently using FlowLayout library: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout and the pill/chip is a LinearLayout atm)

How can I get it so the dynamic text will wrap between the two **(or more)** pills (placed dynamically) and everything will fit/wrap nicely? *(so it reads like a normal sentence)*

-what magic parent layout or super TextView do I have to use?!

Preferally not an answer thats: make a TextView for every word (This item is one of many in a recycler view and the text could get long!)

Would be greatly thankful for any answer/solution! Android layouts are tough.

Comment: tl;dr I'm looking for a way to make it read like 'bob has just promoted you in the the the the Runshaw clan' with unnessicary no new lines (except no room/text wrap)

Comment: `bumped down to next column` -> you usually "bump" up. not down. and column are vertical. This is row.

Comment: Yes, sorry re-worded to row!

Comment: show your codes that a producing this layout )